# add a fit line on the top of histogram graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy, histogram

I am drawing the histogram of exponential distribution as follows. How can I add fit line on the top of this histogram.

```
from scipy.stats import expon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_expon = expon.rvs(size=1000,scale=1,loc=0)
# the histogram of the data
plt.hist(data_expon, 100, density=True, facecolor='r', alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel('exponential')
plt.ylabel('PDF')

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scaling-and-fitting-to-a-log-normal-distribution-using-a-logarithmic-axis-in-pyt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001607/scaling-and-fitting-to-a-log-normal-distribution-using-a-logarithmic-axis-in-pyt)

Comment: Also read [scaling-the-fitted-pdf-of-a-log-normal-distribution-to-the-histrogram-in-python/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34893615/scaling-the-fitted-pdf-of-a-log-normal-distribution-to-the-histrogram-in-python/)

Comment: You can also try [seaborn's kde plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html)